# Migrating from IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity 3.x to 4.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When I was about to update the IdentityServer project in my solution, I ran into some issues.

**In Login method:**

`IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs`

- ConsentResponse doesn’t contain a definition for Denied.

```
await _interaction.GrantConsentAsync(context, ConsentResponse.Denied);
```

- IClientStore doesn’t contain definition for IsPkceClientAsync.

```
if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
```

**In BuildLoginViewModelAsync Method:**

`IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs`

- AccountOptions doesn’t contain definition for WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName

```
var providers = schemes
    .Where(x => x.DisplayName != null ||
                (x.Name.Equals(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    )
    .Select(x => new ExternalProvider
    {
        DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
        AuthenticationScheme = x.Name
   }).ToList();
```

- AuthorizationRequest doesn’t contain definition for ClientId

```
var client = await _clientStore.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(context.ClientId);
```

**In Callback method:**

`IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs`

- The name ‘ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc’ does not exist in the current context

```
ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
ProcessLoginCallbackForWsFed(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
ProcessLoginCallbackForSaml2p(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
```

- No overload method "SignInAsync" takes 5 arguments.

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, name, provider, localSignInProps, additionalLocalClaims.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research and came up with the following: You can change as follow:

**In Login method:** `IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs`

> ConsentResponse doesn’t contain a definition for Denied.

```
await _interaction.GrantConsentAsync(context, ConsentResponse.Denied);

Change to:

await _interaction.DenyAuthorizationAsync(context, AuthorizationError.AccessDenied);
```

> IClientStore doesn’t contain definition for IsPkceClientAsync.

```
if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))

Change to:

if (context.IsNativeClient())
```

**In BuildLoginViewModelAsync Method:** `IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs`

> AccountOptions doesn’t contain definition for WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName

```
var providers = schemes
    .Where(x => x.DisplayName != null ||
                (x.Name.Equals(AccountOptions.WindowsAuthenticationSchemeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    )
    .Select(x => new ExternalProvider
    {
        DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
        AuthenticationScheme = x.Name
   }).ToList();

Change to:

var providers = schemes
   .Where(x => x.DisplayName != null)
   .Select(x => new ExternalProvider
   {
      DisplayName = x.DisplayName ?? x.Name,
      AuthenticationScheme = x.Name
   }).ToList();
```

> AuthorizationRequest doesn’t contain definition for ClientId

```
var client = await _clientStore.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(context.ClientId);

Change to:

var client = await _clientStore.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(context.Client.ClientId);
```

**In Callback method:** `IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs`

> The name ‘ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc’ does not exist in the current context

```
ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
ProcessLoginCallbackForWsFed(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
ProcessLoginCallbackForSaml2p(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

Change to:

ProcessLoginCallback(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);
```

> No overload method "SignInAsync" takes 5 arguments.

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, name, provider, localSignInProps, additionalLocalClaims.ToArray());

Change to:

var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id)
{
    DisplayName = name,
    IdentityProvider = provider,
    AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
};
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);
```

Comment: You know how to migrate the ScopesRequested property from GetAuthorizationContextAsync?

 var request = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
            if (request != null)
            {
                if (request.ScopesRequested.Any())
                {

Comment: @DaveMorrison I think you can use `request.ValidatedResources.ParsedScopes.Any()`

Comment: Hero thanks. I am going through the migration atm.